# How to get offset included in timestamp with time zone into a variable using npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a query that takes a table which has a 'timestamp with timezone' column and returns the timestamp in the context of the server timezone.

As an example, the row contains `2023-02-01T23:00:00+00` but when retrieved using the context of `Europe/Paris` timezone it shows the value with an offset of +1:

[image]

When retrieving via npgsql I have tried mapping to a DateTimeOffset but I'm always getting the UTC value, I never get the +1 offset included.

I have also tried using NodaTime but get the same issue: UTC with no offset :

```
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    var dto = reader.GetFieldValue<DateTimeOffset>(0);              
    var instant = reader.GetFieldValue<Instant>(0);
    var zonedDateTime = reader.GetFieldValue<ZonedDateTime>(0);
    var offsetDateTime = reader.GetFieldValue<OffsetDateTime>(0);
}
```

How can I get the local time with the offset via npgsql and into my C# code? Is this even possible? As PGAdmin shows the `local+offset` time I assume that this is also passed back but can't find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you query a `timestamptz` as text, PG converts it to the (server) local time zone as defined in the `Timezone` parameter. This usually is not what you want - different users live in different time zones, and the system time zone that happens to be configured on the database server isn't generally important. While it's possible to pre-set `Timezone` to the user

The more usual pattern is to do any time zone conversion out of the database, in .NET. In other words, you would simply use .NET APIs to convert the UTC DateTime (or Instant, if you're using Nodatime) which you get from Npgsql to whatever time zone you want.

However, if you want to do the time zone conversion in the database, you can simply convert your `timestamptz` to text and get that:

```sql
SELECT my_column::text FROM my_table;
```

This would be similar to what happens when you query in PGAdmin. However, what you get back is a text, and not a structured timestamp; PostgreSQL simply does not support a data time that combines a timestamp with an offset.

But I again recommend thinking carefully about why you want PG to do the time zone conversion for you, and whether that's a good idea etc.